# Azure data factory IR ODBC - Connection failed

Tags: azure, odbc, azure-data-factory

Trying to connect from ADF to self hosted IR ODBC. In IR ODBC Test is successful , but not in ADF then I try to test connection.

- Where is that Internal Server Error saved?
- What should I change to get connected?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrade of self hosted IR to .NET 4.8 was able to connect